# Laravel 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a link that fetches a JSON file from a web link, and puts it in a directory in `storage/app/internal/commons`:

(I added the actual link to see if that's the issue)

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

downloadLatestId();
function downloadLatestId(){

    $contents = file_get_contents("https://static.api.nexon.co.kr/fifaonline4/latest/spid.json");
    Storage::disk('local')->put('internal/commons/id.json', $contents);
}
```

which returns

```php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Storage' not found in C:\dir\to\my\project\app\Commons\web\myCLass.php:12
```

The stack trace is thrown in the `Storage::disk` line.

My file directory is following:

```
app\Commons\web\id.json
storage\app\internal\commons\id.jso
```

Comment: how are you referencing this myClass file? where are you trying to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import it on the top:

```
namespace ...;
use Storage;
```

Or you have to add a `\` before it if you don't want to import it

```
\Storage::disk('local')->put('internal/commons/id.json', $contents);
```

If it doesn't work, check inside your `config/app.php` file, inside the `alias` array if there is an entry with `Storage` as key; if not, add this like to your `alias` array:

```
'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
```

Comment: Sorry, I did have that part already, just forgot to put it in. Edited. the backslash doesn't work either.

Comment: check inside your config app if there is 'Storage'=>... inside the alias array

Comment: There's already an entry in the array, listed as `'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class`.

Comment: try deleting all the files inside the bootstrap/cache folder

Comment: Tried `php artisan cache:clear` and manually deleting the `cache` folder, but returns the sae error :(

Comment: Try a `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: also if @user3532758 solution doesn't work, post the whole class

Comment: I think it won't. OP is getting the content of the file using file get content. That's a string now. Can't store a string using storage. Error is probably because storage isn't getting a proper file.

Comment: @user3532758 I posted the entire class, with the actual link.

Comment: @user3532758 that is what `put` takes as the second argument, the file contents you want to put into the file, which is going to be a string or a resource

Comment: @lagbox yeah I stand corrected. Thank you! I tested OPs code and it works perfectly.